# Broken links in imported guitar questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, content-import, hyperlinks

Hello,

Relevant question:

[Poor quality guitars that don't tune](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/1691/poor-quality-guitars-that-dont-tune)

The answers and comments give links to guitar.stackexchange.com/... Those were broken during the import. Also, fixing them isn't trivial as not only the base site address changed, but also the post numbers in the URLs.

If the mapping between old <-> new question and answer ID's was preserved somewhere, maybe the links can be fixed automatically to point to the correct posts on music.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I've been updating the links manually as I go along, but an automated method would definitely be better.  Some of the questions don't exist anymore, of course. If you can edit questions/answers manually, great, if it's a comment just flag for a mod to edit it.

Comment: BTW- can mods edit the links in comments?

Comment: @Kos Yep, that's what I meant. If you see a comment with a bad link, flag it and we'll edit it. Ideally provide the correct link :P

Comment: Kos and @MatthewRead, I've added mappings below, hopefully they help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of posts that link to guitars.se.  If you fix a link, please remove it from the list:

[done.]

Comment: Thanks to rshallit in particular for doing a huge number of these.

Answer (score 2):

A google site search *should* help find these:

http://www.google.com/search?q=site:music.stackexchange.com/questions+guitars.stackexchange.com#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=site:music.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions+http%3A%2F%2Fguitars.stackexchange.com&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=bb00a8cd1aea9d79&biw=1280&bih=679

But it keeps returning questions that have been fixed. Anyone's Google-fu good enough to refine this search so it won't do that?

Answer (score 2):

For reference, here is a list of the migrated question mapping (questions only, I didn't include answers, but all urls should have the question id in it anyway, so the information needed can be found):

381 to [976](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/976)
556 to [979](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/979)
427 to [985](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/985)
512 to [992](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/992)
606 to [993](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/993)
540 to [997](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/997)
467 to [1001](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1001)
596 to [1004](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1004)
366 to [1008](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1008)
579 to [1012](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1012)
383 to [1015](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1015)
479 to [1018](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1018)
602 to [1024](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1024)
486 to [1026](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1026)
582 to [1031](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1031)
624 to [1033](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1033)
513 to [1035](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1035)
551 to [1038](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1038)
609 to [1042](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1042)
390 to [1046](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1046)
411 to [1049](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1049)
453 to [1051](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1051)
412 to [1053](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1053)
375 to [1055](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1055)
409 to [1058](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1058)
576 to [1061](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1061)
394 to [1064](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1064)
495 to [1069](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1069)
374 to [1072](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1072)
489 to [1075](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1075)
619 to [1079](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1079)
616 to [1082](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1082)
458 to [1085](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1085)
428 to [1089](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1089)
572 to [1093](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1093)
633 to [1101](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1101)
472 to [1103](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1103)
548 to [1106](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1106)
442 to [1111](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1111)
524 to [1115](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1115)
484 to [1119](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1119)
446 to [1122](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1122)
454 to [1126](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1126)
421 to [1130](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1130)
600 to [1136](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1136)
504 to [1139](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1139)
464 to [1142](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1142)
376 to [1145](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1145)
652 to [1148](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1148)
535 to [1151](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1151)
498 to [1161](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1161)
656 to [1164](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1164)
635 to [1169](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1169)
662 to [1173](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1173)
642 to [1179](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1179)
641 to [1182](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1182)
651 to [1185](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1185)
413 to [1192](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1192)
541 to [1195](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1195)
478 to [1201](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1201)
589 to [1205](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1205)
506 to [1208](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1208)
443 to [1212](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1212)
378 to [1214](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1214)
634 to [1218](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1218)
508 to [1225](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1225)
435 to [1227](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1227)
445 to [1232](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1232)
566 to [1235](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1235)
404 to [1240](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1240)
527 to [1243](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1243)
400 to [1247](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1247)
612 to [1256](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1256)
653 to [1258](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1258)
654 to [1262](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1262)
643 to [1266](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1266)
625 to [1268](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1268)
627 to [1271](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1271)
630 to [1273](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1273)
204 to [1277](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1277)
126 to [1279](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1279)
46 to [1285](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1285)
156 to [1295](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1295)
20 to [1301](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1301)
240 to [1305](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1305)
198 to [1308](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1308)
191 to [1311](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1311)
58 to [1317](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1317)
165 to [1322](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1322)
186 to [1330](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1330)
79 to [1332](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1332)
239 to [1335](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1335)
7 to [1338](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1338)
222 to [1345](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1345)
55 to [1348](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1348)
1 to [1354](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1354)
157 to [1359](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1359)
265 to [1361](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1361)
43 to [1363](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1363)
6 to [1368](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1368)
150 to [1372](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1372)
271 to [1379](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1379)
9 to [1383](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1383)
256 to [1386](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1386)
62 to [1391](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1391)
89 to [1394](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1394)
153 to [1401](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1401)
151 to [1410](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1410)
361 to [1413](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1413)
282 to [1415](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1415)
12 to [1419](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1419)
16 to [1428](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1428)
263 to [1439](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1439)
320 to [1446](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1446)
299 to [1453](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1453)
142 to [1455](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1455)
275 to [1458](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1458)
77 to [1462](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1462)
171 to [1467](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1467)
22 to [1472](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1472)
272 to [1480](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1480)
34 to [1482](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1482)
354 to [1490](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1490)
143 to [1494](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1494)
172 to [1496](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1496)
353 to [1505](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1505)
38 to [1507](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1507)
218 to [1511](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1511)
109 to [1519](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1519)
236 to [1523](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1523)
290 to [1526](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1526)
323 to [1530](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1530)
13 to [1533](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1533)
25 to [1538](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1538)
237 to [1553](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1553)
75 to [1561](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1561)
346 to [1567](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1567)
227 to [1570](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1570)
35 to [1573](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1573)
345 to [1580](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1580)
316 to [1582](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1582)
302 to [1585](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1585)
340 to [1594](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1594)
314 to [1596](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1596)
315 to [1602](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1602)
68 to [1604](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1604)
3 to [1612](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1612)
5 to [1615](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1615)
228 to [1619](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1619)
144 to [1621](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1621)
363 to [1629](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1629)
312 to [1637](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1637)
248 to [1642](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1642)
352 to [1647](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1647)
169 to [1652](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1652)
47 to [1657](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1657)
258 to [1659](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1659)
145 to [1661](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1661)
67 to [1663](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1663)
124 to [1672](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1672)
291 to [1677](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1677)
158 to [1683](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1683)
199 to [1687](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1687)
334 to [1691](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1691)
308 to [1695](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1695)
349 to [1709](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1709)
1852 to [1712](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1712)
1755 to [1714](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1714)
1468 to [1718](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1718)
1285 to [1723](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1723)
786 to [1727](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1727)
916 to [1734](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1734)
1008 to [1739](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1739)
1768 to [1742](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1742)
785 to [1746](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1746)
959 to [1749](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1749)
1645 to [1754](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1754)
850 to [1758](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1758)
1295 to [1763](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1763)
1622 to [1767](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1767)
1506 to [1773](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1773)
1809 to [1778](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1778)
708 to [1784](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1784)
934 to [1787](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1787)
1644 to [1793](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1793)
734 to [1796](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1796)
1232 to [1801](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1801)
1278 to [1805](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1805)
796 to [1809](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1809)
1372 to [1818](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1818)
1041 to [1821](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1821)
1301 to [1827](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1827)
1011 to [1834](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1834)
1861 to [1838](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1838)
1114 to [1847](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1847)
702 to [1857](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1857)
668 to [1859](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1859)
887 to [1863](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1863)
1657 to [1867](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1867)
755 to [1869](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1869)
905 to [1875](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1875)
1392 to [1881](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1881)
941 to [1883](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1883)
1888 to [1887](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1887)
1857 to [1893](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1893)
1705 to [1897](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1897)
1585 to [1900](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1900)
706 to [1904](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1904)
1261 to [1908](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1908)
1142 to [1913](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1913)
1128 to [1917](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1917)
1175 to [1932](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1932)
1848 to [1936](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1936)
819 to [1941](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1941)
1807 to [1944](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1944)
1393 to [1948](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1948)
1129 to [1951](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1951)
1029 to [1956](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1956)
685 to [1958](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1958)
1649 to [1960](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1960)
736 to [1965](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1965)
1209 to [1969](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1969)
1773 to [1971](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1971)
750 to [1977](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1977)
1639 to [1983](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1983)
696 to [1985](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1985)
1185 to [1992](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1992)
768 to [1995](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1995)
802 to [1999](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/1999)
1197 to [2002](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2002)
1063 to [2005](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2005)
1398 to [2009](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2009)
1770 to [2015](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2015)
1625 to [2019](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2019)
1168 to [2022](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2022)
1119 to [2028](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2028)
1289 to [2032](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2032)
840 to [2036](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2036)
859 to [2040](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2040)
1839 to [2043](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2043)
1406 to [2047](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2047)
864 to [2050](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2050)
712 to [2052](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2052)
1031 to [2055](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2055)
984 to [2058](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2058)
1339 to [2060](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2060)
1157 to [2070](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2070)
813 to [2072](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2072)
1327 to [2075](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2075)
869 to [2080](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2080)
895 to [2084](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2084)
1599 to [2089](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2089)
1169 to [2096](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2096)
1058 to [2099](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2099)
1801 to [2103](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2103)
1436 to [2108](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2108)
1424 to [2113](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2113)
1414 to [2115](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2115)
1067 to [2119](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2119)
1658 to [2124](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2124)
1499 to [2126](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2126)
1090 to [2129](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2129)
1693 to [2137](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2137)
1545 to [2141](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2141)
759 to [2144](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2144)
1033 to [2149](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2149)
1125 to [2152](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2152)
714 to [2157](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2157)
1221 to [2162](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2162)
747 to [2164](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2164)
1595 to [2166](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2166)
1635 to [2169](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2169)
1559 to [2175](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2175)
1498 to [2179](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2179)
1284 to [2188](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2188)
863 to [2190](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2190)
1288 to [2196](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2196)
1612 to [2202](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2202)
1101 to [2207](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2207)
1098 to [2212](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2212)
806 to [2214](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2214)
1162 to [2217](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2217)
1739 to [2220](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2220)
775 to [2224](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2224)
1308 to [2230](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2230)
1091 to [2234](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2234)
1053 to [2238](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2238)
1489 to [2244](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2244)
1236 to [2248](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2248)
700 to [2250](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2250)
1433 to [2254](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2254)
1544 to [2257](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2257)
1578 to [2262](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2262)
1572 to [2265](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2265)
1223 to [2270](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2270)
1744 to [2280](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2280)
1720 to [2282](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2282)
772 to [2284](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2284)
1283 to [2288](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2288)
1589 to [2290](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2290)
1073 to [2295](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2295)
1333 to [2298](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2298)
1051 to [2304](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2304)
896 to [2308](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2308)
1244 to [2312](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2312)
1415 to [2316](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2316)
1248 to [2320](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2320)
1814 to [2326](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2326)
1368 to [2330](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2330)
1126 to [2337](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2337)
844 to [2340](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2340)
1084 to [2345](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2345)
1268 to [2348](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2348)
946 to [2354](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2354)
1714 to [2359](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2359)
1552 to [2361](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2361)
1387 to [2364](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2364)
1725 to [2368](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2368)
1314 to [2372](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2372)
807 to [2375](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2375)
980 to [2380](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2380)
667 to [2382](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2382)
713 to [2386](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2386)
1722 to [2390](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2390)
1869 to [2393](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2393)
1400 to [2396](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2396)
783 to [2398](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2398)
1241 to [2403](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2403)
1661 to [2406](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2406)
1732 to [2414](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2414)
1207 to [2418](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2418)
781 to [2421](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2421)
831 to [2424](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2424)
1486 to [2427](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2427)
1854 to [2435](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2435)
1671 to [2440](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2440)
1660 to [2445](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2445)
871 to [2449](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2449)
1782 to [2454](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2454)
1600 to [2457](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2457)
1558 to [2461](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2461)
1342 to [2466](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2466)
1540 to [2472](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2472)
1061 to [2475](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2475)
951 to [2477](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2477)
1517 to [2479](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2479)
1794 to [2483](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2483)
1310 to [2486](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2486)
1037 to [2491](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2491)
1700 to [2495](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2495)
793 to [2499](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2499)
995 to [2501](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2501)
1646 to [2505](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2505)
789 to [2511](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2511)
825 to [2513](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2513)
686 to [2518](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2518)
975 to [2525](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2525)
743 to [2527](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2527)
1718 to [2530](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2530)
1173 to [2536](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2536)
1427 to [2544](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2544)
855 to [2547](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2547)
945 to [2552](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2552)
1026 to [2554](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2554)
1469 to [2556](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2556)
1668 to [2562](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2562)
1834 to [2565](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2565)
1746 to [2568](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2568)
1319 to [2571](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2571)
760 to [2574](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2574)
1727 to [2577](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2577)
1180 to [2580](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2580)
805 to [2582](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2582)
1728 to [2587](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2587)
933 to [2592](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2592)
1320 to [2595](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2595)
1523 to [2598](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2598)
1825 to [2602](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2602)
1046 to [2609](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2609)
898 to [2611](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2611)
1017 to [2616](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2616)
1762 to [2624](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2624)
1120 to [2627](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2627)
877 to [2630](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2630)
684 to [2636](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2636)
1188 to [2638](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2638)
710 to [2644](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2644)
697 to [2648](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2648)
1568 to [2650](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2650)
1377 to [2654](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2654)
1881 to [2658](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2658)
977 to [2662](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2662)
1431 to [2667](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2667)
1680 to [2670](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2670)
1551 to [2673](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2673)
1887 to [2676](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2676)
1153 to [2680](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2680)
1034 to [2685](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2685)
1743 to [2687](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2687)
1198 to [2690](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2690)
1711 to [2696](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2696)
1915 to [2699](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2699)
1904 to [2702](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2702)
1969 to [2708](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2708)
2005 to [2710](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2710)
1970 to [2712](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2712)
1935 to [2717](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2717)
1990 to [2720](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2720)
1916 to [2726](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2726)
1951 to [2728](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2728)
1930 to [2730](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2730)
1908 to [2732](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2732)
1984 to [2737](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2737)
1983 to [2741](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2741)
1977 to [2745](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2745)
954 to [2749](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2749)
917 to [2754](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2754)
1688 to [2757](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2757)
1777 to [2771](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2771)
1105 to [2778](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2778)
690 to [2781](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2781)
1356 to [2784](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2784)
1528 to [2787](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2787)
1899 to [2792](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2792)
906 to [2795](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2795)
881 to [2799](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2799)
1002 to [2801](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2801)
1539 to [2807](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2807)
1932 to [2811](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2811)
925 to [2814](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2814)
1824 to [2819](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2819)
1760 to [2822](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2822)
1914 to [2824](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2824)
1531 to [2829](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2829)
1004 to [2834](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2834)
814 to [2837](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2837)
1571 to [2843](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2843)
1872 to [2846](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2846)
1411 to [2849](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2849)
1943 to [2852](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2852)
1953 to [2858](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2858)
1896 to [2861](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2861)
2003 to [2866](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2866)
1940 to [2868](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2868)
1947 to [2871](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2871)
1967 to [2873](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2873)
1936 to [2875](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2875)
1999 to [2878](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/2878)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of posts that have comments linking to guitars.se.  Remove them as the links are corrected.  Only moderators will be able to fix these:

[done.]